# Obj-C, need to create an oject to hold strings / numbers and then update with calculations?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to create an array or a dictionary to hold a string and a value, I'm producing a pie chart. I need to loop through the rows from my database query and add a string and a price to an object.

I then need to add up the total price of all the items and change the value in the objects so they are less than 1.

I'm not explaining this very well...

This is what I'm replacing with dynamic data.

```
BNPieChart* chart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Orange 10%"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.2 withName:@"Fandango 10%"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Blue 10%"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Cerulean 10%"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.3 withName:@"Green 10%"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Yellow 10%"];
[chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Pink 10%"];
```

Notice that when you add the slice values they total 1.

I've tried using a dictionary but the price doesn't seem to fit as a value or a key.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

if(error_code == SQLITE_OK) {

    while(sqlite3_step(statementTMP) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        // HERE you need to put the data into an array so you can 
        // perform calculations on it after the array is filled

        // get price and category string

        [dictData setObject:accumPrice forKey:category];
        i ++;
    }
}
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: Is price a primitive (i.e. float or double)? If so, use NSNumber. Collections (NSDictionary, etc.) require an object and won't work with scalars, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a `NSNumber` to store int,float,double etc inside of a dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

if(error_code == SQLITE_OK) {

    while(sqlite3_step(statementTMP) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        // HERE you need to put the data into an array so you can 
        // perform calculations on it after the array is filled

        // get price and category string

        [dictData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:accumPrice] forKey:category];
        i ++;
    }
}
```

[NSNumber Class Refernce](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)